# Transiting through Heathrow on separate tickets

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, lhr, air-canada, serbia

I will be travelling from Belgrade (BEG) to London (LHR) on Air Serbia and then from LHR to Toronto (YYZ) on Air Canada on separate tickets. Both of the flights arrive at/leave from the same terminal (T2) at LHR and I will have only a cabin bag and no check in bags. I am a Canadian permanent resident (Indian passport and a Canadian PR card) and as such I believe I will not require a visa to transit (checked at https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa). My questions are:

1. Will I be able to use the flights connections route (and hence not have to go through immigration again) given that I have only hand baggage but considering that both the journeys are on separate tickets?
2. Will Air Serbia let me board at Belgrade given that I hold no visa for the UK and for them UK will be my destination? I can show them a confirmed ticket for Air Canada and a boarding pass from Air Canada too (if I am able to check in online and generate a boarding pass online)

PS: I know this may have been answered several times before but just checking if anyone has any experience with Air Serbia. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will I be able to use the flights connections route

Maybe, but I don't think you can rely on it. For starters, you need to check in with AC for your flight to Toronto. During Corona, check in for international flights is an unpredictable process. It often requires a manual doc check at the check-in counter. You may not be able to get a boarding pass online or airside at the gate or service counter, even if you can make your way there.

> Will Air Serbia let me board at Belgrade

Unlikely, but you can always ask. Air Serbia sold you a ticket to London and as far as they are concerned you get off the plane in London and what you do there is none of their business. Some airlines will accept 3rd party "proof of onward travel" but it's safer for them if they don't and the terms and conditions typically spell this out.

Given that we are in Pandemic, I would NOT do this, especially not with a 1.5 hour layover (assuming JU380 + AC857).

Things are really unpredictable: Two weeks ago I flew from FRA to AMS. I physically HAD to show up at the counter to get a boarding pass and it took over an hours since everyone had to check in manually and they only had two counters staffed. A couple of days later I flew onward to Berlin. I had no trouble getting my boarding pass two days ahead online and it took me less than 5 minutes to get to the gate. You just don't know until you get there.